# Restore deleted files from commit

Tags: git, commit, restore

I've just done the following series of steps and I don't know how to recover my files.

1. git add file.txt
2. git commit -m "Message"
3. rm file.txt
4. git commit -am "Message"

Ideally I should have pushed my changes after step 2 and then delete but I forgot. Is there a way to recover the file?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can recover the file from the previous revision with the `checkout` command:

```
git checkout HEAD^ file.txt
```

If the file has been deleted in an earlier commit (let's assume `229da640`), you can recover it by passing commit's sha1, followed by `^`:

```
git checkout 229da640^ file.txt
```

If you haven't pushed the commit yet, you might rather want to reset the commit instead:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

This will reset your working tree to the same state as of the previous commit. All changes after the previous commit will be gone.

If you don't want all changes to be gone, just undo the act of the commit itself, you can reset without the `--hard` option, and restore the deleted file with:

```
git reset HEAD^
git checkout file.txt
```

Comment: Is the `^file.txt` necessary? What if I don't remember the filename? I'm thinking of a (silly) case in which I'd write a new feature in its own file, then a year later remove it, then wanting it back another year later. Would said feature file show up just by checking out that first commit (the one right before I removed it)?

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do that, try it

First find the commit id of the commit that deleted your file. It will give you a summary of commits which deleted files.

> git log --diff-filter=D --summary
>
> git checkout 84sdhfddbdddf~1

```
Note- 84sdhfddbddd is your commit id
```

through this you can easily recover all deleted files.

---